How to avoid making network call more than once?
I have a Spring Request Scoped component that makes a network call to fetch some data:
@Component
@RequestScope
public class NetworkDataProvider {

    @Inject
    private ServiceClient serviceClient;    

    public Optional<List<String>> getSomeData() {
         return serviceClient.getSomeData(); // makes network request to get the data
    }
}

I want to use this data in multiple other components:
@Component
public class Component1 {
    
    @Inject
    private NetworkDataProvider networkDataProvider;

    public String getSomething() {
        Optional<List<String>> data = networkDataProvider.getSomeData();
        ...
    }
}

@Component
public class Component2 {
    
    @Inject
    private NetworkDataProvider networkDataProvider;

    public String getSomething() {
        Optional<List<String>> data = networkDataProvider.getSomeData();
        ...
    }
}

Then these components are being used in the controller:
@Controller
public class MyController {
    
    @Inject
    private Component1 component1;

    @Inject
    private Component2 Component2;

    public ModelAndView mv() {
        String string1 = component1.getSomething();
        String string2 = component2.getSomething();
        ...
    }
}

Now since ServiceClient will called two times from two separate components, it will make two network requests.
What will be the best way to avoid making multiple network requests and reusing the data from the same request?

How long will the data fetched from the network remain valid? Will it eventually expire, requiring a new request to retrieve fresh data, or is it sufficient to fetch the data just once for the entire lifetime of the application?

Try @Cacheable annotation from Spring. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching
You can apply this caching on the method NetworkDataProvider.getSomeData().

I ended up putting the network call inside the constructor to make sure it would get called only once during the object creation. Seems to be working well.

In my opinion it's bad idea. A network call can take unpredictable time (in some range), it can end in a timeout or it can even throw an exception. Too much logic for a constructor.

Yeah so what? I don't think it makes a difference. It's working well.
